# How to edit startup applications from recovery mode?

Tags: 12.04, recovery-mode

I accidentally messed up Ubuntu by adding a startup application that causes it to freeze after logging in, how can I change this through recovery mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From recovery mode, you can manualy remove the entry by deleting the file in the startup directory: `/etc/xdg/autostart/`